# Removing onclick funtion using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a host that has a template for nav bars, I can style it but cannot edit the content within it. The search function brings up a search box, however I have developed an advanced search on the actual page /search.. Is there a way to remove the onclick and target from this link? I cannot access the actual HTML for this to just remove it, therefore I have to have something override it.

```
 <a class="mainmenu" href="/search" onclick="showhide(document.getElementById('search_menu')); return false;" target="_blank">Search</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by you can't access the HTML? Can you do it with Javascript? Are you trying to hack a webpage?

Comment: @Rojo, no I am not trying to hack a webpage. This is a web host where the menu is a template, so the code I have access to is '<div class="headerbar">
  <div id="headerbar-top">
   <div class="wrap">
    <a href="{U_INDEX}" id="logo"><img loading="lazy" src="{LOGO}" alt="{L_INDEX}"/></a>

    <ul class="navbar navlinks{NAVBAR_BORDERLESS}">
     <li>{GENERATED_NAV_BAR}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>' Obviously, I can't access the ability to remove the onclick from the search function.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **removeAttribute** function to remove those attributes. below is a working example.

```js
window.onload=function(){
    var anc=document.getElementsByClassName("mainmenu");
    anc[0].removeAttribute("target");
    anc[0].removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

```html
<a class="mainmenu" href="/search" onclick="showhide(document.getElementById('search_menu')); return false;" target="_blank">Search</a>
```

Comment: `var` and `getElementsByClassName` ? we live in 2021 man

Comment: @vdegenne does this solution hv problem?

Comment: I didn't say the solution has problem. Just old syntax used.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning null to the IDL attribute will clear the inline handler:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('.mainmenu');
a.onclick = null;
a.removeAttribute('target');
```

```html
<a class="mainmenu" href="/search" onclick="showhide(document.getElementById('search_menu')); return false;" target="_blank">Search</a>
```

Comment: Wait, are you sure that it’s possible to set an object’s properties if it’s const?

Comment: Definitely. All `const` does is prevent the *variable name* from being reassigned to something else. It doesn't prevent the object from being mutated.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.mainmenu')` is better practice. It is usually a bad habit to select things with wide selectors.

Comment: @vdegenne, I tried this code and it's still allowing the link to produce the pop up window instead of directing to the page, any ideas?

Comment: @mikehunni I double-checked in a standalone file, the `_target` looks to be successfully removed; clicking the link in a standalone file results in the whole page redirecting to `/search`

Comment: @CertainPerformance you need to remove href attribute to remove /search

Comment: @NegiRox The href attribute needs to stay, right? As OP says *however I have developed an advanced search on the actual page /search.*. Pretty sure he wants it to work as a normal link, just remove the inline handler and `_blank` target.

Comment: @certainperformance correct, I just want to remove the host overriding the link to the pop up on click.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `target` and `onclick` attribute and replace the `href` attribute value with `javascript:void(0)`. You can use the below code for this.

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('mainmenu')[0];
a.removeAttribute('onclick');
a.removeAttribute('target');
a.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
```

```html
<a class="mainmenu" href="/search" onclick="showhide(document.getElementById('search_menu')); return false;" target="_blank">Search</a>
```